# How to run mod_php and fastcgi side-by-side?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fastcgi, mod-php

How would it be possible to run certain scripts (this could be in either a vhost or directory setting in the apache conf) to run as mod_php when the current server configuration is running FPM/FastCGI?

Server OS: Ubuntu-Server 11.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easy answer would be just to install `mod_php` and `php_fcgi` - and do not define the `x-application` PHP handler in any of your configs. Then it would use `mod_php`.

Answer (score 1):

To run PHP both with mod_php and fastcgi, you can also use `PHP-FPM` and Apache `mod_actions`

Install `mod_fcgi` and `mod_actions` for Apache. Install and configure `PHP-FPM`.

And add to the virtual host config following block

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
<IfModule mod_actions.c>
    FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/<document_root_path>/php.fastcgi -socket /var/run/php-fpm.sock

    Action php-fcgi-script /php.fastcgi virtual

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
        SetHandler php-fcgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I prefer to run PHP-FPM listening a UNIX socket.

But you can also configure your PHP-FPM to run on local port, so you should change `-socket` config parameter to the `-host ip:port`

`FastCGIExternalServer` configuration http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiExternalServer